# Putting tags above blocks when looked at

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way that I could put tags on blocks when a player looks at it? If you are confused about what I mean by tags, I am talking about the kind that you get from naming a mob with a name tag. Anyways, like I said, is there any way to do this with a command or something? I want players to be able to see the name of the block they are looking at. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mod that will do this for Every block in the game and is compatible with quite a few other mods.. it is oddly enough called [WAILA](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1846244-) or [What Am I Looking At](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1846244-).

There is however no way to do this with out modding the game. It is not part of the default game like the scoreboards and such are.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a specific case, but it is worth noting:

A named item (which you renamed using an anvil), placed in an item frame does have its name displayed, similar to named mobs or players, when you look at it.

This has been added in 1.7.2, according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame#History)